# Replication of postgres database at table level

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.0, postgresql-9.2

I am just wondering whether it would be possible to replicate *only a table* in a postgres database with another database instance. For example, lets say that I have a postgres instance running at hostA and another instance at hostB. Lets say i have a relation called "user" in a database called "database1" in hostA and i want to replicate this with a different database called "database2" at hostB. How can we go about it?

Comment: I was able to do it using  "SQL Generator" from IntelliJ's DBMS tool(Data Grip).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slony-I can do this: http://slony.info/documentation/2.1/preface.html#INTRODUCTION

But Slony might be quite an overhead if it's really only a single table.

For just a single table you could write a trigger that updates the table on the other host through [DbLink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html).